# How to change page title according to path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

im writing a react app and i need to change the page title according to the path im currently on, for now i have the page title change according to the navbar tab click, and i have another button on the navbar (on the top-bar section of it) redirects me to a page within the app but since the button is not inside the side-bar (hamburger menu) the page title dosent change.

this is Navbar.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavbarData } from "./NavbarData";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import "./Navbar.css";
import Hamburger from "./Icons/Hamburger.svg";
import closeIcon from "./Icons/Close.svg";
import "./Icons/p_logo_color.png";
import Persona from "./Icons/Persona.svg";

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  const [pageName, setPageName] = useState('Operational Overview');
  const location = useLocation();

  const getPageTitleByUrl = (path) => {
    NavbarData.filter((navItem) => {
    
      if(navItem.path === path) {
        setPageName(navItem.title);
      }
      
    } )
    

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if(location.pathname) {
      getPageTitleByUrl(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location] ); 
  

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
             <img src={Hamburger} alt="hamburger" onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
          <div className="pageTitle"><h1>{pageName}</h1></div>
          <Link to='userconfig'>
          <div><img className="userIcon" src={Persona} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="userButton">User123#</div>
          </Link>
          <Link to='/' className="logout-button" >Log Out</Link>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className="navbar-toggle">
              <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
              <img src={closeIcon} alt=''/>
              </Link>
            </li>
            {NavbarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
        
                    <span className="navbutton-text" ><span className="navbutton-icon">{item.icon}</span>{item.title}</span>
                    
                    
                  </Link>
                  
                </li>
                
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

This is NavbarData.js:

```
import React from 'react'


import settingsIcon from './Icons/Settings.svg';
import startpageIcon from './Icons/startpage.svg';
import performance from './Icons/performance.svg';
import bars from './Icons/bars.svg';
import simulation from './Icons/simulation.svg';
import plan from    './Icons/plan.svg';
import fraud from './Icons/fraud.svg';



export const NavbarData = [
    {
        title: 'Operational Overview',
        path: '/monitoringoverview',
        icon: <img src={startpageIcon} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Performance Quality",
        path: "/performancequality",
        icon: <img src={performance} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Finance",
        path: "/finance",
        icon: <img src={bars} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Fraud and Anomalies",
        path: "/fraudandanomalies",
        icon: <img src={fraud} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Simulation",
        path: "/simulation",
        icon: <img src={simulation} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Planning",
        path: "/planning",
        icon: <img src={plan} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Settings",
        path: "/settings",
        icon: <img src={settingsIcon} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    
  


]
```

I have a function which takes the path saved inside NavbarData.js but the user button is not there

```
  const getPageTitleByUrl = (path) => {
    NavbarData.filter((navItem) => {
    
      if(navItem.path === path) {
        setPageName(navItem.title);
      }
      
    } )
    

  };
```

Comment: use react-helmet to change page title according to routes

Answer (score 0):

Add the below useEffect hook in NavBar component

```
useEffect(() => {
    //this will be executed while the pageName state will change
    document.title=pageName; 
}, [pageName]);
```